# Java - Parse an object name from an arrayList created from a csv file

Tags: java

I've created a function that gets the objects location within the project folders and it's index and throws that address into an arrayList. What I need to do now is parse the data in that arrayList so that it just returns the name of each Item.

First here's the Item class:

```
public class Item {

public String name;
public int x;
public int y;

//constructor

public Item(String n) {
    name = n;
}


}
```

The function that loads the Items into the arrayList

```
public ArrayList<Item> loadItems()
{
    InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.items);
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            items.add(new Item(line));
            System.out.println("Hello Matt" + items);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Reading list of Items failed!", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error closing file reader.", e);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Here we create a radius around the already populated item so that it can be "retrieved" when a user touches the screen. That Item is then sent to the Found arrayList

```
ArrayList<Item> mItems = loadItems();
static final ArrayList<Item> found = new ArrayList<>();

 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            for (int i = mItems.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                float dx = mItems.get(i).x - X;
                float dy = mItems.get(i).y - Y;

                if ((dx) * (dx) + (dy) * (dy) < radius * radius) {

                  found.add(mItems.get(i));
                    mItems.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("Bye " + mItems);
                }

            }
```

Then the getInventory function returns the found list, this is where the data needs to be parsed

```
    public static ArrayList<Item> getInventory() {
    //called from MainActivity.java

    return found;
}
```

Comment: `getInventory function returns the found list, this is where the data needs to be parsed` what does it mean exactly? At the beginning you said you need to return array list with names only, so return type should be `ArrayList<String>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
ArrayList<Item> foundList = getInventory();
for(int i =0;i<foundList.size();i++){
System.out.println("Name" + foundList.get(i).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After revisiting it this was the solution I came up with. UI isn't super pretty but the functionality is there. Change added to getInventory()

```
ArrayList<Item> inv = DrawSurface.getInventory(); 
     List<String> treasure = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (Item item: inv)
        { 
         String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");  
         treasure.add(item.name + newline); 
        }
```